# What does Facebook like button represent for App Store apps?

Tags: ios, ios-appstore, facebook, app-store-connect

On an iOS application's App Store reviews tab, there is a Facebook like button.

Anybody know what it does when a user clicks on it? Does it show on the user's Facebook feed or does it like a Facebook page for the app?

[image]

Comment: Have a look at: [Facebook like button](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Facebook_like_button)

Comment: I think this button will trigger a wall post on Facebook, if it's connected to the iPhone. This wall post will be a link to download the app. 
It needs to be tested though, I looked a while back on how to add this option while publishing my apps on the app store but couldn't find any information about it. After going through the facebook sdk for the iPhone I didn't find anything about it, I concluded that this option is triggered on Apple's side.

Answer (score 1):

If you are logged in Facebook from Setting app, then it will show the "Like button" on App Store app detail.

It will like the application URL from your account.